# Akshata colour and significance

Tags: puja

Are there any differences between yellow and red coloured akshatas? Is any colour preferred over another in the context of a specific type of puja or vratha? Any benefits of using one colour over other?

Comment: I believe these are dependent on regional traditions. Some mix turmeric which makes the rice yellow while others mix kumkuma which makes it red.Some also mix Vibhuti. If you see the fact that red is associated with Devi, white with Shiva and yellow with Vishnu you can understand why these slight differences exist.